# Twilio: Dial out from conference

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I have an incoming phone call that is waiting in a conference. While they are waiting, our application looks for an appropriate rep based on some business logic to connect to them too. If we are unable to find a rep, we would like to forward the call to a general number. It's possible that this number will dial to voicemail.

Normally, I would dial out, and when the phone is picked up I would connect the call to the conference. The issue with that workflow is the person in the conference will not hear the call being dialed out, and it also presents challenges with voicemails (I need the inbound call to know if they are leaving a voicemail).

How can I either remove the inbound caller from the conference and dial out to the generic number, or call out from the conference?

Answer (score 0):

I found from here: https://twilio.radicalskills.com/projects/conference-calling-voice/3.html (under "modify live calls") that using the original call Sid you should be able to remove them and send new twiml instructions. Whoopie!

edit: I was asked to expand on my answer. Here is what I'm doing:

1. The caller is already waiting in a conference, I need to "remove" them and dial out.
2. Using the Rest API I send a Redirect to the original call sid of the call that was put into a conference.
3. The Redirect url returns a twiml dial app to the number I want the original call to be connected to.

That's it :)

Comment: Glad you found an answer your self. However, I recommend you to just include external link as a reference : your answer here should be self-explanatory.

Also, you can accept your own answer to mark the question as resolved and help other people find out your solution.